# ggplot2: dodge overlapping when y axis is not count/frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, group

I'm trying to make a side-by-side bar plot, by gender, with age category on the x axis and completion time on the y axis.  One of my age categories has no males, so there is no data and there should be no bar there.  The dodge_position2(preserve = "single") option won't work because in my example I need to specify a y aesthetic (I don't just want a frequency of all the datapoints in that age category).

The instructions [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) show exactly my problem (with the double-wide bar), but I cannot find any information on how to modify it to accept an x and y aesthetic.  I suspect I need to manually create these in a much more convoluted way.  (Oh, also stacked bar graph won't work for my purpose.)

My code attempts:

The version with a double-wide bar for an age category missing males:

```
p<-ggplot(d, aes(x=AgeGroup, y=Time, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#2A800A','#9CDC46'))
p
```

This version just makes almost all my bars disappear, I have no idea why:

```
p<-ggplot(d, aes(x=AgeGroup, y=Time, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(preserve="single"), width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#2A800A','#9CDC46'))
p
```

This gives me error `stat_count() must only have an x or y aesthetic.`

```
p<-ggplot(d, aes(x=AgeGroup, y=Time, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#2A800A','#9CDC46'))
p
```

I'm not familiar enough with `ggplot2` to create this from scratch.  I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Missing `stat="identity"` in the `geom_bar` function

Comment: Take a look at the help for `?geom_bar`: *There are two types of bar charts: geom_bar() and geom_col(). geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col() instead. geom_bar() uses stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases at each x position. geom_col() uses stat_identity(): it leaves the data as is.*

Comment: @JonSpring - aha!!!  Thank you!  I tried once with geom_col() but to be honest I probably didn't pay close enough attention to the resulting error, and looking up geom_col() vs. geom_bar() was one of the rabbit holes I needed to go down but I chose others instead (poor judgment, obviously!)  Thank you, I'll give that a try this morning,

Comment: You will be more likely to get useful advice if you can provide a reproducible example. 1) Sample of data (as code, e.g. using the `dput` function), 2) what you expect/want, and 3) what you've tried. (Current question has #3 and I'm not sure I understand #2.)